# converting RDF to OWL

Tags: xml-serialization, rdf, owl, rdflib

I want to generate RDF code that follows the OWL format. I am able to generate an RDF file, but I need to convert it into OWL. Below is the RDF that I can generate.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
   xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/nodetypes/2012/04/24/vehicle/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/nodetypes/2012/04/24/vehicle/2">
    <ns1:nodetype_ptr_id>2</ns1:nodetype_ptr_id>
    <ns1:slug>vehicle</ns1:slug>
    <ns1:last_update>2012-04-24 23:49:36.633689</ns1:last_update>
    <ns1:end_publication>2042-03-15 00:00:00</ns1:end_publication>
    <ns1:tree_id>2</ns1:tree_id>
    <ns1:featured>False</ns1:featured>
    <ns1:parent_id>None</ns1:parent_id>
    <ns1:content></ns1:content>
    <ns1:rating_score>0</ns1:rating_score>
    <ns1:rating_votes>0</ns1:rating_votes>
    <ns1:start_publication>2012-04-24 23:49:15</ns1:start_publication>
    <ns1:level>0</ns1:level>
    <ns1:creation_date>2012-04-24 23:49:15</ns1:creation_date>
    <ns1:status>2</ns1:status>
    <ns1:template>gstudio/nodetype_detail.html</ns1:template>
    <ns1:content_org>None</ns1:content_org>
    <ns1:excerpt></ns1:excerpt>
    <ns1:plural>vehicles</ns1:plural>
    <ns1:comment_enabled>True</ns1:comment_enabled>
    <ns1:password></ns1:password>
    <ns1:title>vehicle</ns1:title>
    <ns1:login_required>False</ns1:login_required>
    <ns1:pingback_enabled>True</ns1:pingback_enabled>
    <ns1:rurl></ns1:rurl>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 11):

As cygri says, the job is done. However, there are now two additional normative syntaxes: [OWL/XML](http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/converter/) and the [Functional syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/) which is used to specify what's an OWL ontology and to specify its direct semantics. In addition to these, there are non-normative syntaxes for OWL: [The Manchester syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/) and all the RDF serialisation syntaxes ([Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/), [N-Triples](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-testcases/#ntriples), [Notation3](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/n3/), [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/), [RDF/JSON](http://docs.api.talis.com/platform-api/output-types/rdf-json), [HDT](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2011/SUBM-HDT-20110330/), etc). The [RDF Working Group](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdf-wg/wiki/Main_Page) is working at [making Turtle a standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/), as well as [a JSON serialisation](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdf-wg/wiki/TF-JSON).

In order to switch format, you can use [the converter at University of Manchester](http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/converter/), which can output RDF/XML, Turtle, OWL/XML, Manchester syntax, Functional syntax and also LaTeX (for nice rendering in articles).

Edit: Since February 2014, [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/), [N-Triples](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/), [N-Quads](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/), and [Trig](https://www.w3.org/TR/trig/) are normative syntaxes for RDF.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! the converter at university of manchester is really great to get the things done but i don't want to use any converter to switch from rdf/xml to owl/xml instead i need a code that can help me to do this.is it possible???? plzz help...

Comment: thanks...but i m not using java instead working with python on django framework..

Answer (score 9):

You're already done. What you have there is an RDF/XML file. The normative syntax for OWL is RDF/XML. So it is an OWL file too.