# Improvement needed in RDF format

Tags: rdf, owl, rdflib, rdfs, rdfstore

I am able to generate an RDF but the format is not proper because of which i m not able to fire proper Sparql QUERY ..I need to improve the format of the RDF.I want to have classes, instance ,property to be there in RDF for Objecttype,Attribbutetype,Relationtype..can u guys help me out in deriving that RDF ..code snnipet would be of great help...

i m pasting the rdf that i m able to generate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
   xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/nodetypes/2012/04/24/vehicle/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 >
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/nodetypes/2012/04/24/vehicle/2">
    <ns1:nodetype_ptr_id>2</ns1:nodetype_ptr_id>
    <ns1:slug>vehicle</ns1:slug>
    <ns1:last_update>2012-04-24 23:49:36.633689</ns1:last_update>
    <ns1:end_publication>2042-03-15 00:00:00</ns1:end_publication>
    <ns1:tree_id>2</ns1:tree_id>
    <ns1:featured>False</ns1:featured>
    <ns1:parent_id>None</ns1:parent_id>
    <ns1:content></ns1:content>
    <ns1:rating_score>0</ns1:rating_score>
    <ns1:rating_votes>0</ns1:rating_votes>
    <ns1:start_publication>2012-04-24 23:49:15</ns1:start_publication>
    <ns1:level>0</ns1:level>
    <ns1:creation_date>2012-04-24 23:49:15</ns1:creation_date>
    <ns1:nodemodel>Objecttype</ns1:nodemodel>
    <ns1:status>2</ns1:status>
    <ns1:template>gstudio/nodetype_detail.html</ns1:template>
    <ns1:content_org>None</ns1:content_org>
    <ns1:excerpt></ns1:excerpt>
    <ns1:plural>vehicles</ns1:plural>
    <ns1:comment_enabled>True</ns1:comment_enabled>
    <ns1:password></ns1:password>
    <ns1:title>vehicle</ns1:title>
    <ns1:login_required>False</ns1:login_required>
    <ns1:pingback_enabled>True</ns1:pingback_enabled>
    <ns1:rurl></ns1:rurl>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

in the code there is an rdf description of

```
 <ns1:nodemodel>Objecttype</ns1:nodemodel>.
```

since it is an objecttype it should be placed under rdf:class.I am a new bee in this field and i don't have much knowledge about RDF..so any kind of help would be really really helpful.

Comment: also seems to be a repost of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313026/converting-rdf-to-owl

Answer (score 1):

The presence of those things shouldn't affect your ability to do SPARQL queries.

Besides, that kind of information is normally in your OWL ontology rather than the RDF.  The pretty formatting you can put into the RDF is just that ... formatting ... not informational.  It disappears when you ingest the RDF into a triple store.

Comment: ok...what i want is to display the rdf in the following format `<owl:Class rdf:about="Person"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="Animal"/>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="salary"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;real"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>` how can we get the RDF in this format

Comment: @AmitaSingh - but why?  You have had a number of people TELLING you that what you are doing is technically unnecessary.  How many more people will it take?

Comment: Hey Stephen thanks a ton for making me realize that whatever i want is unnecessary.. actually my team members want to improve the formatting that why i was keen to do that.

Comment: Well ... that's not the reason you gave in your question.  And that is what people are responding to ... not this other reason that you've just deigned to tell us about.  Besides, your team members would be better of using tools like Protoge rather than attempting to read and/or write RDF/OWL files by hand.